# WCF : What is the need of Correlation State in Message Inspector?

Tags: wcf

I am using message inspector at the server side.
Regarding Correlation state my understanding is as below -

1. Correlation state is populated on the `AfterReceiveRequest` & `BeforeSendReply`.
2. Correlation state object contains few parts of message which are common in request & response.

But not exactly able to visualize its usage in practical terms.
Can some one please help me to understand this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first web search hit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx) on your title says:

> After the user code on the service operation processed the request, and the reply is created into a Message object, BeforeSendReply is called on the inspector code, with the message object and the correlation state, which is whatever AfterReceiveRequest returned – **this way the code can correlate the two parts of the message inspection for a single client request.**

Comment: Hi thanks, in fact I went through the article as well as `Carlos` pluralsight course, before posting the query here. Info I was looking for is... what does it mean to correlate two parts of message inspection here.. any real world example, please ?

Comment: I can't find a more detailed source, but it has to do with statelessness. The message inspector doesn't know that it has already seen a certain message, unless the message has a unique identifier, so the inspector can [correlate](http://xkcd.com/552/) messages (that is, in this: know these messages parts belong to the same request). - I'm wondering why you're asking this though, are _you_ having a real world problem, or are you just curious?